# Issues with adb shell screenrecord

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to record a video of a blank screen with some change ocurring at the end. I notice that screen record chomps frames at the beginning or the end which are visually similar. Is there a way I can stop it from doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you can't do this according to official instruction